# Debugging cdc-acm kernel module

Tags: linux, kernel-module, cdc

I am trying to fix a problem I am having on Ubuntu (tried different versions including the latest 13.10) with a USB device talking CDC/ACM on one of its interfaces. The kernel module handling this kind of devices only reports

> cdc_acm 6-2:1.1: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
>
> cdc_acm: probe of 6-2:1.1 failed with error -22

in dmesg and that is it. Nothing about "Zero length descriptor references" or similar stuff that other people report on the web. So I wanted to find out what the problem might be. I followed the description in http://www.silly-science.co.uk/2012/06/23/lenovo-usb-modem-in-linux-ubuntu-10-04 to compile and load a custom cdc-acm module. First, I changed the two `#undef`s for debug to `#define`s in [cdc-acm.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/usb/class/cdc-acm.c), but I am still not getting any additional output in dmesg.

Changing the version string in cdc-acm.c's `DRIVER_VERSION` define to something else, I can verify that my modified module is indeed loaded. Am I looking for the debug output in the wrong place?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get debug info from cdc_acm in dmesg, and even though I don't have something special to share, these were my steps, using latest kernel as of today 4.2-rc5:

1. Change `DEBUG` and `VERBOSE_DEBUG` `#undef`s to `#define`s in cdc-acm.c.
2. `make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd)/drivers/usb/class modules`
3. `modprobe -r cdc_acm; insmod $(pwd)/drivers/usb/class/cdc-acm.ko`
4. `dmesg` after plugging a compatible device

[...]

[14035.355036] cdc_acm 2-2:1.1: acm_tty_write - write 1

[14035.368040] cdc_acm 2-2:1.1: acm_softint

[14038.156445] cdc_acm 2-2:1.0: acm_tty_close

[14038.173054] cdc_acm 2-2:1.0: acm_ctrl_msg - rq 0x22, val 0x0, len 0x0, result 0

[14038.173059] cdc_acm 2-2:1.0: acm_port_shutdown

[14038.173640] cdc_acm 2-2:1.0: acm_ctrl_irq - urb shutting down with status: -2

[14038.174636] cdc_acm 2-2:1.1: acm_read_bulk_callback - urb 0, len 0

[...]